# Can anybody explain this css to me

Tags: html, css

Maybe its dumb question. But i need to know. I came across this css.

```
p.sansserif {font-family: sans-serif;}
<p> TEXT </p>
```

I usually use like this

```
p {font-family: sans-serif } 
<p> TEXT </p>
```

But both giving me different font style. Tried google but cant a explanation. Tried in dreamweaver with diffrent ways still cant understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule applies to all `<p>` elements that have the class `sansserif`.  So your html would need to be `<p class="sansserif"> TEXT </p>`

The second rule just applies to all `<p>` elements.  This one applies to the element that you have in your question.

Comment: so .sansserif is just a class. got confused because its sounds like font family.

Comment: it is a class name that just happens to sound like a font family

Answer (score 0):

`p.sansserif {font-family: sans-serif;}`

would only apply to `<p class="sansserif"> TEXT </p>`